# Hazelcast-IMap get, does it have auto lock mechanism?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have an IMap with Mapstore configured, it seems when I get from IMap from multiple thread, it does correctly with only fetch 1 time and other will automatically have hits. So I wonder that Imap does auto have lock mechanism on when try to get from cache, nowhere I read actually confirm this but it behave as it has lock.

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `com.hazelcast.core.IMap` [javadoc](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html):

> **Concurrent**, distributed, observable and queryable map.

So the concurrency is guaranteed by design, however it doesn't necessarily mean that locks are used.

From hazelcast [documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#locking-maps):

> Hazelcast Distributed Map (IMap) is thread-safe to meet your thread safety requirements. When these requirements increase or you want to have more control on the concurrency

This can be achieved via a multitude of `lock/unlock` methods.